# Index consolidation of two similar indexes

Tags: sql-server, index, index-tuning, sql-server-2019, nonclustered-index

We have a primary table that drives most of the work within our product with many columns.

Index 1 has a key consisting of: Column A, Column B, Column C, Column D

Index 2 has a key consisting of: Column D, Column A, Column B

The Includes are nearly identical, except Index 2 has Column C as an include when Index 1 has it in the key.

Would Index 2 be a candidate to drop in favor of Index 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, no, the two indexes are not equivalent. But it all depends on the queries you are trying to optimize.

Generally speaking, columns in an index can only be used if, from left to right, the columns of the key are all constrained with equality (ColumnA=somevalue). One of the column can also be constrained with inequalities (ColumnB > somevalue) but then the columns at the right of the inequality one cannot benefit from the index.

So, for example, if you have the following predicate:

```
WHERE ColumnA=valueA AND ColumnB > valueB
```

sql-server can use Index 1 but not Index 2, because there is no predicate on ColumnD, which is the first one on Index2.

Indexes can also be useful for grouping or sorting, but the same rules apply.

```
ORDER by ColumnD, ColumnA
```

can use Index 2 to speed up sorting, but not Index 1.

Comment: I haven't delved deeply into this subject before now and I've only seen very simple index consolidation examples. Thank you for the excellent explanation!